# Approximate linear density function for a normal distribution

Tags: probability, approximation, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm working on implementing [Order Preserving Encryption for Numeric Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20140116112127/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/cs/projects/iis/hdb/Publications/papers/opes.pdf), and part of the algorithm includes approximating density of the distribution as a linear density function $f(p) = qp+r$ where $p$ exists in the distribution.

From the article:

> If a distribution over $[0,ph)$ has the density function $qp + r$, where $p \in [0,ph)$, then for any constant $z > 0$, the mapping function $M(p) = z(\frac{q}{2r}p^2 + p)$ will yield a uniformly distributed set of values.

The algorithm splits up the distribution into a set of "buckets", and a unique density function is needed for each bucket.

If I'm working with a normal distribution over $[0,100)$ with $\mu=65$ and $\sigma=10$, split into buckets $[0,40)$, $[40, 65)$, $[65, 80)$, and $[80,100)$, how can I produce a density function for each bucket?

Comment: I have not read the paper into great details, but seems in part 4 the author mentioned to use a linear spline to model the distribution within each bucket - connecting the densities at the two end points of the bucket.  Not sure if we need to further normalize it as the area under this linear spline will not sum to $1$ in general.